# Show Image Top left part in ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, display

I want to set image top left part in ImageView.

[here is the image of the output i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxfw0.jpg)

[Screen Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV3KF.jpg)

Comment: what should the remaining part require

Comment: yes it's required.

Comment: Is all part is of image or other

Comment: for moving image in ImagView.

Comment: all part require but i want to show only top left part of image in imagview.

Comment: if want to divide screen into 4 part refer the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833883/divide-screen-into-4-equal-parts-android

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample]

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: xml part is already done. but i am getting image from gallery and show in to imageview